# On the structure of the set of Self-Adjoint operators acting on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lie-algebras, quantum-mechanics, noncommutative-algebra

Let us consider the $Hilbert$ Space $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $SA(L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of all self adjoint operators acting on $L^{2}$. I have worked with operators such as $X$, $P$, $X^{2}$, and $P^{2}$ which which are characterized by the commutation relation $$[X,P] = i$$
pleanty of times. Hamiltonians such as $H = \alpha X^{2} + \beta P^{2}$ ($\alpha$ and $\beta$ real) are typical. However, I would like to understand what the most general Self-adjoint operator in $SA(L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ looks like. Am I right to assume that the most general element of $SA(L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is simply an operator valued fucntion $f(X,P)$ of $X$ and $P$? If so what would be necessary and sufficient conditions on $f()$ for $f(X,P)$ to be self-adjoint (I suspect that the image of $f()$ would have to be real valued). Thank you for your time.

Comment: I would recommend reading the wiki article on self-adjoint operators or something similar.

Comment: @s.harp thanks for the recommendation. I have indeed looked at the wikipedia page. In the end my hypothesis would seemingly be confirmed by use of the spectral theory for self adjoint operators. However, my understanding is that these operators should form a Lie Algebra. I am interested in the unitary groups generatred by such a Lie algebra. Indeed $\{ \mathbb{I}, X, P\}$ is closed with respect to the commutator. Now I am wondering how large this algebra can get, i.e. what is the largest Lie Algebra of Self adjoint operators  acting on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: So it would seem that $X$ and $P$ are the generators of the Lie algebra that I am discussing and via spectral theorem any function of  the generators will be another element of said Lie algebra. Sorry for the long message. Thank you Kindly for your time.

Comment: The groups having a Lie algebra like X, I, P are called Heisenberg groups, their representation theory is well understood if I recall correctly. The operators X, P are not bounded, but if you look at the commutant of their spectral resolution you get only 1, so the bi-commutant is all of B(H). With the bi-commutant theorem this means that every bounded operator is in the SOT closure of the algebra generated by these projections.

Comment: @s.harp Thank you kindly for this thoughtful comment.

Comment: I would like to point out that knowing that the sot-closed algebra they generate is all of $B(H)$ does not help at all in getting a picture of what a general operator looks like. For example the finite-rank operators have the same property, and just knowing about finite-rank operators does imply any understanding of other operators.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I see, I am still  hopeful that someone might know what the general operator might look like. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you expec.t Everything that needs to be known about selfadjoint operators is contained in the Spectral Theorem. Which doesn't mean that you can get an obvious general description of a fixed arbitrary operator on a fixed Hilbert space.